# SpannableStringBuilder not displaying text in Text View

Tags: android, kotlin, spannablestringbuilder

I'm trying to make an array of strings individually clickable within a text view  that is within a RecyclerView (each tag would pass different data, which is fetched from the api on load). I've created the string using `SpannableStringBuilder` as below within the `bindView` method.

```
fun bindView(link: PostsModel)
     val tags = link.topics
     var spans = SpannableStringBuilder()

     for (tag in tags) {
         val string = SpannableString(tag.name)
         string.setSpan(ClickableTags(tag.name), 0, tag.name.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
         spans.append(string)
     }
}
```

Then I set it to the text view.

```
view.headerTags.setText(spans, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
```

If I `println()` the contents of `spans` and `view.headerTags.text`, I can see it contains a string of tags, so it seems to be working. However, when testing in the app, it's not appearing in the text view.

[image]

If I set `view.headerTags.text = "Tags should appear here"`, it works, so I'm not sure there's a problem with the text view.

[image]

Can't see to work out why it wouldn't appear, especially if the console is printing out the contents of text view? Can anyone let me know what I might be missing here?

Comment: So looked like the text colour may have been transparent or yellow? Added `            string.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, tag.name.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)` which seems to now work

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
    Spannable word2 = new SpannableString("By signing in, I agree to The xxxxx\nxxxxxxx Terms of Service and Privacy Policy.");
    word2.setSpan(clickableSpan, 44, 60, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    word2.setSpan(clickableSpan1, 65, 80, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(word2);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

   ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, ReadTermsOfServiceActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("FROM", "termsservices");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
    }
};
```

Comment: I need to use `SpannableStringBuilder` as I get back an array of tags, so I don't know what the string will be until `bindView()` is firing.